# Узнать версию фронта из бэка

Tags: frontend, backend

Сталкивался ли кто нибудь с подобной задачей и как решали? Суть в том что при обновлении фронта пользователи, которые не обновили страницу могут отправлять запросы со старого. Задача в том чтобы на стороне бэка понимать с какой версии фронта пришел запрос.

Answer (score 1):

Мы указывали текущую версию в URL запроса 
http://example.com/api/v1/query

Так же были реализации с кастомным Request Header

Comment: Еще есть вариант с указанием версии API в одном из обязательных параметров запроса. Тогда можно менять версии отдельно для каждого метода.